# How to extract CSS in angular 2 with webpack

Tags: angular, stylus

I am trying to separate CSS in angular 2 project. I have used postcss along with stylus and nib and rupture. And integrating ExtractTextPlugin returns expecting array of strings error.

```
{
            test: /\.styl$/,

            use: [
                    'to-string-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'stylus-loader',
                        options: {
                            use: [rupture(), nib()],
                            import: ['~nib/lib/nib/index.styl']
                        },
                    },
                ]
        }
```